# Firebase retrieve data from multiple node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How retrieve all publication of user '04a86MjHKnUyPT173jyzgoYcVyA3' and publication of his friends

[image]

[image]

```
   mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Publication").child(iduser);
            mDatabase.keepSynced(true);


            firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AdapterPublication, CardViewHolder>(

                    AdapterPublication.class,
                    R.layout.card_view,
                    CardViewHolder.class,
                    mDatabase )
```

Comment: English, please...